# Photo Gallery Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a simple  photo gallery using html css and javascript. At the top of my project i have 5 thumbnails which hold 5 images. Below my thumbnails I have a div that is the size of the original image size. What I would like to happen is when the user click any of the thumbnail photos to show in the div below the thumbnails the photo in its original size. I have create the start of the project but i don't know how to finish it. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out to finish the code that i have to add(css and JS) in order to finish this.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
div id="img-thumbnails">
  <img src="assets/imgs/img-01.jpg">
  <img src="assets/imgs/img-02.jpg">
  <img src="assets/imgs/img-03.jpg">
  <img src="assets/imgs/img-04.jpg">
  <img src="assets/imgs/img-05.jpg">
</div>

 <div id="img-original">

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#img-thumbnails {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#img-thumbnails img {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#img-original {
    height:500px;
    width:800px;
    border:10px solid black;
    margin:30px auto;
}
```

Comment: use Photobox - https://github.com/yairEO/photobox

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example implementation, you may use it as a guideline as to how to solve your issue.

I use divs in place of images here as I have none to link to.

```js
var preview = document.getElementById('pretend_view');
var images = document.getElementById('pretend_images');
var thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('#pretend_images > div');

thumbnails.forEach(function(elem){
 elem.onclick = onClick.bind(null, elem);
});

function onClick(elem, e){
 clearPreview();
  addToPreview(elem);
}

function clearPreview(){
 var elem = document.querySelector('.preview');
  
  if(elem){
    elem.className = elem.className.replace('preview', '');
    images.appendChild(elem);
  }
}

function addToPreview(elem){
 elem.className = 'preview';
  preview.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
#pretend_images > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#pretend_preview {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    border:10px solid black;
    margin:30px auto;
}

#a {
  background-color: black;
}

#b {
  background-color: blue;
}

#c {
  background-color: green;
}

#d {
  background-color: pink;
}

.preview {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pretend_images">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
  <div id="d"></div>
</div>

 <div id="pretend_view"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code is working! Cheers.